# Flash based countdown timer in HH:MM:SS using user's system clock

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, countdown

Hi
Tasked with creating a countdown timer which I've done before but never using the user's system clock. Does anyone know if its possoble to access the system time from within flash?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Date](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html) class.